# Would Apache Gora fit when you have to build an application which writes/reads from a set of databases?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, cassandra, hbase, gora

Would Apache Gora fit when you have to build an application which writes/reads from a set of databases including SQLServer, MongoDB, HBase & Cassandra?

The idea is to develop an application which is capable of performing CRUD operations across databases? Request 1 goes to SQLServer, Request 2 goes to MongoDB and Request 3 goes to HBase and so on. The Request will have the information as to which database the application should hit and there is a finite list of databases.

Are there any alternatives?

Any pointers?

Let me know if any other information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I would say "yes", **except** accessing SQL Server (not supported).

Two things I can tell you as BIG tips to begin:

1. Create your datastores with this [DataStoreFactory#createDataStore()](https://github.com/apache/gora/blob/apache-gora-0.8/gora-core/src/main/java/org/apache/gora/store/DataStoreFactory.java#L166) method that allows to configure a different "gora.properties" content, and Configuration.
2. Remember that each `gora-xxx-mapping.xml` is shared between all the connections to a same backend.

Alternatives:

- [Kundera](https://github.com/Impetus/Kundera), maybe?

-- Edit from comments:

There is a gora-sql module but it had to be disabled years ago because of some license issues. If you look at the [modules in the pom](https://github.com/apache/gora/blob/master/pom.xml#L743), you will see that gora-sql is not being compiled. No one took the staff to rebuild it :(

About point 2, it can exist `Application1MongoDB` and `Application2MongoDB`: If they are different applications, they can have a different `gora-xxx-mapping.xml` in each one's classpath.
If they are datastores instances from calls to `#createDataStore()` (in the same application), then all the mappings will have to go in the casspath's `gora-xxx-mapping.xml`. It is just a tip I advised that I found tricky.

More alternatives:

- Hibertane OGM as told in the comments.
- EclipseLink (although does not support much backends)
- DataNucleus

Comment: thanks for the response.

I thought there was a component gora-sql which would help in connecting to any RDBMS. 

From point 2 I understand that there could only be one MongoDB and not Application1MongoDB and Application2MongoDB. 


I'm looking at Kundera and Hibernate OGM as alternatives

Comment: Thanks for your update, this is clear, the same application cannot have two xml, the intent was to have the single generic CRUD service across all the application databases, which doesn't seem to be feasible.

Comment: Uhm... I'm sorry for explaining myself wrong, since I see it quite feasible (except SQLServer). If you want, we can goto a chat and you can tell me the details of what you need to detail the solution or discard the possibility.